# Why doesn't the shell prompt occur after I "cat" a FIFO special file or create a FIFO special file in my program?

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I'm learning named pipes in Linux and write the following program to try it out.

The following program creates a FIFO special file named "test.fifo", then it creates two child processes to read and write from that named pipe.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <wait.h>

int main() {
    pid_t pid[2];

    // Create FIFO special file
    mkfifo("test.fifo", 0644);

    pid[0] = fork();
    if (pid[0] < 0) {
        printf("Fail to fork child process #0\n");
        return 1;
    } else if (pid[0] == 0) {
        // Open FIFO special file in read mode
        int in = open("test.fifo", O_RDONLY);

        // Read data
        char buf[256];
        read(in, buf, 256);
        printf("Child process #0 received: %s\n", buf);

        // Close pipe
        close(in);
        return 0;
    }

    pid[1] = fork();
    if (pid[1] < 0) {
        printf("Fail to fork child process #1\n");
        return 1;
    } else if (pid[1] == 0) {
        // Open FIFO special file in write mode
        int out = open("test.fifo", O_WRONLY);

        // Write data
        char buf[256] = {0};
        strcpy(buf, "Hello world");
        write(out, buf, 256);

        // Close pipe
        close(out);
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sometimes this program runs normally. But sometimes after this program runs, my shell prompt disappears.

```
MyUserName@MyHostName:~$ ./a.out
MyUserName@MyHostName:~$ Child process #0 received: Hello world
(This is an empty line, no shell prompt occurs)
```

I try to type and run the command `ls` in the empty line, and the command works. So it seems that the program has exited successfully, and it's just that the shell prompt doesn't occur.

The same thing will happen if I run the command `cat test.fifo`.

```
MyUserName@MyHostName:~$ cat test.fifo
(This is an empty line, no shell prompt occurs)
```

What's happening and why is this happening?

Comment: Shell prompt disappearing is usually due to incompatible characters being outputted to terminal

Comment: When you cat the test.info file, you'll be sending all the 256 bytes of the file to the screen.  That will include the random memory contents inside "buf[]" beyond the "hello world" string.  As Calculus says, the screen will interpret those as display control characters.  Not sure why you're getting the same effect from running the C program though, since %s will stop at the null terminator.   One other point - your fork() for pid[1] is superfluous - you only need 2 processes (output and input), and that's creating a third.

Comment: You had a new shell prompt printed -- it's the one after the `./a.out` invocation, but just before the `Child process #0` message. The shell can't tell that your program left parts of itself still running that printed additional text after the prompt; consequently, it (the shell) has no way of knowing it needs to print another prompt (or whatever else you might desire it to do in this case instead).

Comment: ...and insofar as shell *could* look for left-over child processes and poll until they exited, if it tried to do that, it would prevent programs from being able to background themselves, so it would be undesirable behavior.

Comment: Oh! I forgot to use `wait()` in the parent process. So if the parent process exited before the child process, the shell prompt will be printed before the "Child process #0..." stuff. Thank you all for the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the parent program doesn't `wait(2)` for the children to finish, when it does `exit(2)` (on the last `return 0;` in main) the shell shows the prompt.  But you don't control (and don't know even) if the children have finished printing their output, so probably the shell prompt is overwritten by output from one of the children.  But the shell is always outputting the prompt, but as it doesn't follow a new line (the cursor remains in the same line) something can make it to be overwritten by the output of the children.

try to put the following just before the last `return 0;`:

```
wait(NULL);
wait(NULL); /* as you did two fork()s you can make up to two wait()s */
```

and then, the program termination will be synchronized with the children.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments!

Just like Charles Duffy says, the shell prompt has already be printed -- it's the one after the ./a.out invocation. I forgot to use `wait()` in the parent process. So if the parent process exited before the child process, the shell prompt will be printed before the "Child process #0..." stuff.

As for the `cat test.fifo`, I made a mistake in the description. If I run `cat test.fifo`, not only the shell prompt doesn't appear, but the `ls` command will also fail to work if I type and run it on the empty line. This is because the `cat` command is trying to open the FIFO special file in read mode, but no process is trying to open the FIFO special file in write mode.

From https://linux.die.net/man/7/fifo we know that, "The FIFO must be opened on both ends (reading and writing) before data can be passed. Normally, opening the FIFO blocks until the other end is opened also." So the `cat test.fifo` command is actually blocked and hasn't exited yet, and thus the shell prompt doesn't occur.